# How to change a scene's exported variable via tool mode?

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot3

I have a scene as such:

[image]

where the main scene has a `show_title` variable and before I export the game I run the following plugin:

```
tool
extends EditorExportPlugin
class_name CustomExportPlugin


func _export_begin(features, is_debug, path, flags):
    # do some checks before exporting
    ...
```

How do I set the `show_title=true` within the `Main.tscn` every time before exporting?

**Note:** I am using godot version 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Modifying an scene from a `tool` script

- You `load` the scene.

  ```
  var my_scene := load("res://main.tscn") as PacketScene
  ```
- You `instance` it (`instantiate` in Godot 4).

  ```
  var my_instance := my_scene.instance()
  ```
- You modify the instance:

  ```
  my_instance.show_title = true
  ```
- You package it again:

  ```
  my_scene = PackedScene.new()
  scene.pack(my_instance)
  ```
- And save it:

  ```
  ResourceSaver.save(my_scene, "res://main.tscn")
  ```

Yes, this modifies the project. And no, `EditorExportPlugin` **IN GODOT 3**, does not make this any easier.

**IN GODOT 4** you can override `_begin_customize_resources` to return true, and override `_customize_resource` to return the modified `PackedScene`. This way you don't have to save it, and thus the project is not modified.

---

### What I would do

In the script on the root of `main.tscn`:

```
func _ready() -> void:
    show_title = true
```

If you need this set before `_ready`, you can do it in `_init` instead.

If that script is not a tool script, that won't happen in the editor. If it is, then you can check if the code is running in the editor with `Engine.editor_hint` (`Engine.is_editor_hint()` in Godot 4).

Comment: This works! and I intentionally used `EditorExportPlugin` so I don't accidentally export the game without the title showing. I didn't use `_ready` since I don't want to see the title every time while development. Also the changes aren't reflected in the scene until I reopen it, is there a way I can trigger refresh from the script?

Comment: @M.R.M. I believe this would do it: `EditorInterface.get_resource_filesystem().scan()` - Edit: I think you want you don't want to see the title while debugging, right? Aside from `Engine.is_editor_hint()` to detect if you are running *in* the editor, you can detect if you are running *form* the editor with `OS.has_feature("editor")`, and you can detect if it is a debug export with `OS.is_debug_build()`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, based on [@Theraot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78048702/22302305) this is what the complete script looks like:

```
tool
extends EditorExportPlugin

const MAIN_SCENE_PATH="res://Main.tscn"

func _export_begin(features, is_debug, path, flags):
    
    var main_scene := preload(MAIN_SCENE_PATH) as PackedScene
    var new_instance := main_scene.instance()
    new_instance.show_title = true
    
    main_scene = PackedScene.new()
    main_scene.pack(new_instance)
    
    ResourceSaver.save(MAIN_SCENE_PATH, main_scene)
```